# I Run set /A Prov=%RANDOM% * 6 / 32768 and get the same number (5), every, single, time

Tags: batch-file, random

Running this line of code in a .bat file with delayed Expansion enabled.
I've tried:

```
set /A Prov=!RANDOM! * 6 / 32768 (Always Equals 5)
```

I've tried:

```
set /A Prov=!RANDOM! * 5 / 32768 (Always Equals 4)
```

I've tried:

```
set /a Prov=%random% %%6 + 1 (Always Equals 3, except rarely equals 6)
```

No other code is writing to Prov, and it's not in a loop or for
What could be causing this! >,_ <

I was expecting it to give me a different number between 1 and 6 each time the command or batch file was run, however it's always the same, even when the file is closed and run again.

Comment: I get always a different number, I guess you set the variable RANDOM with something like `set RANDOM=30002`

Comment: When i Run in the same script:
set /A yeses=!RANDOM! * 6 / 32768
echo %yeses%
set /A yeses=!RANDOM!
echo %yeses%
set /a yesseis=%random% * 6 / 32768
echo %yeseis%

I get:
5
30261
ECHO is off.

Comment: Then you should close and reopen your command window. Check if a RANDOM  variable is set (shouldn't be) with `set random`

Comment: doing set RANDOM=30002 just kept the variable Random as the same number for the whole program

Comment: Never create/set a variable named RANDOM, then the real random mechanism can't work anymore

Comment: i don't have that originally, random is only used as a variable any time it is mentioned

Comment: What do you get if you type `set random`? Or put this line into  your script. And do you get always `30261` for  `echo %random%`?

Comment: when adding set random into the script, it continues to give a random number only when random variable is used without any math operations with it, whenever set /a is used to times or add to %random% or !random! it doesnt give a value at all, or uses the last working random value, even if the variable is used in a different position or order...

Comment: Which Windows Version you are using?

Comment: If you run your (small) program several times in a small amount of time (i.e. the same clock second) _or_ starting cmd.exe each time, your "random" number will be always the same. I suggest you to use this "randomize" initialization (with Delayed Expansion Enabled): `for /L %%i in (0,1,%time:~-1%) do set "x=!random!"`

Answer (score 0):

This batch program should work

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "random"
echo #1 !random! !random!
```

Expected output

```
The environment variable "random" is not defined.  
#1 13400 3633
```

You should get an error message for the `set "random"` command.
And you should get two different values in `test #1`

Comment: set "random"
Environment variable random not defined

echo #1 !random! !random!
#1 4409 20789

Comment: @LukeCGG Then the rest of your script should also work, just copy&paste it behind

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why it is like this, but removing the spaces fixed my problem...

instead of:

```
set /a Prov=!random! * 6 / 32768 + 1
```

doing:

```
set /a Prov=!random!*6/32768+1
```

This worked in my situation, but I don't understand why that would cause issues?

Comment: spaces don't matter with the `set /a` command (although they *do* in a simple `set`). Actually, the code in your question runs fine for me. Maybe you had some other invisible character instead of a space somewhere (and propagated it with copy/paste)?

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ possibly